# Using cheese in noodle dishes

Tags: cheese, noodles, korean-cuisine

A while ago I went to a Korean restaurant and ordered a noodle dish without really looking at the menu (as I sometimes tend to do). I was surprised when I was served something that had cheese in it, and even though I know that Korean dishes can contain a variety of common but not commonly used ingredients (e.g. Korean Army Stew with Spam and other bits and pieces) this was still unusual for me.

However, I have asked a few people about hot noodle dishes with cheese and no one seems to know much about this. I am wondering if this is a Korean cooking technique/style or if it is also used in other cuisines and dishes around the world.

Is there a well-known Korean hot noodle dish that includes cheese? If so what is it called?

Comment: Are you asking whether noodles or pasta are commonly served with cheese?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  It's not clear what your actual question is, Michael.  Can you edit your ask so that the question you want answered is clearer?

Comment: Surprisingly, cheese goes quite well with noodles! Some Japanese people add cheese to their ramen. There's also a (recently invented) Cantonese dish, cheese egg noodles (usually with seafood, typically shrimp or lobster), that is very popular.

Answer (score 5):

My friend who was in Korea for a few months said that they are obsessed with cheese. It's not a traditional ingredient, but in modern cuisine they try to introduce cheese to some of the dishes - I guess this is the case you described. In my city (Poznań, Poland) there is a Korean restaurant specializing in bibimbap and the serve one option with mozarella cheese (and kimchi, it's a gorgeous combination).

Comment: If anyone's curious, Maangchi is a Korean-American YouTube chef who uses cheese in several recipes because she likes it, or when she visited Korea last time it was really popular. Buldak, tteokgalbi, and bokkeumbap, and gyeranpan come to mind. The Eatyourkimchi YT channel made a lot of Korean food videos before the creators relocated to Japan. They had a lot of interesting cheese encounters, and also made an instructional video for adding processed cheese and kimchi to shin ramyeon. There are other channels if you want to see more takes on Korean food. Have fun!

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer and comments. It wasn't a ramen dish that I had but I will have to check out the YT channel you mentioned. I think there are too many Mok Bang videos for my liking when it comes to Korean food, but there are definitely others worth checking out :)

Comment: https://www.xkcd.com/1609/?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Ham and Skittles? I don't think so... :D